# For what values of ''$a$'' , does this Improper Integral converges?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

For which values of  ''$a$'',   does the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^a}\;\mathrm dx$$ converges?

I have shown that  $$\left| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x^a}\;\mathrm dx \right|\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{n} \frac 1{x^a}\;\mathrm dx,$$ which converges if $a > 1$. Are there other values of $a$ for which the integral converges?

Comment: What makes you think $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{n} \frac{1}{x^a} dx$ converges when $a \lt 1$? (You have problems as $n$ increases)

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: In fact, $\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin x}{x^a}\;\mathrm dx$ converges for $a>0$ and has the limit $\int_0^\infty \frac {\sin x}{x^a}\;\mathrm dx \xrightarrow{a\searrow 0} 1$.

Comment: Can you explain how I can show that?

Comment: Your edit does not help much as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{n} \frac{1}{x^a} dx$ diverges near $x=0$ for $a \ge 1$.  But note that $\sin x \approx x$ for $x$ near $0$ while you have an alternating sum for large $x$

Comment: More precisely, $\frac 2 \pi x \le \sin x \le x$ on $(0,\frac\pi 2)$.

Comment: Fyi: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771577/512032

Comment: Can we show just the convergence of the integral using less advanced techniques, I mean without calculating the value?

Comment: @KanuKim I don't think that's true. As KaviRamaMurthy points out in his answer, the integral converges for 1 < a < 2. And for other values of a doesn't.

Comment: Since this question is a better question than the question of which it is closed as a duplicate, I think this one could be reopened. The other has been closed for being asked poorly.

Comment: Integration by parts gives $$\int_0^L\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1-\cos(L)}{L^\alpha}+\alpha\int_0^L\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ which handles $0\lt\alpha\le1$. For $1\lt\alpha\lt2$, the integral near $0$ is okay since $|\!\sin(x)|\le|x|$. This is, if by $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x$, you mean $\lim\limits_{L\to\infty}\int_0^L\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,\mathrm{d}x$. If you mean Lebesgue integrability, then for $\alpha\le1$, the integral does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Both integrability near 0 and integrability near $\infty$ have to be taken into account. The integral exists for $1<a<2$ and the improper integral $\int_0 ^{\infty} \frac {\sin (x)} x \, dx$ exists and the value is $\frac {\pi} 2$. [ This is proved in almost all texts on Complex Analysis]. For other values of $a$ the integral does not exist.

Comment: Can't this be proved without using complex analysis, I mean just the existence part?

Comment: @user398623 you have different proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175042/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xx-dx-with-fubini-theorem

Comment: How can it be shown that integral exist for $1<a<2$ ?

Comment: If you allow $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi2$, then you are considering the improper integral as a limit, and not considering Lebesgue integrability. In that case, the integral exists for $0\lt\alpha\lt2$.