# Evaluate fourier integral : $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{isx} ds}{(s-\tfrac{7i}{2})^2 + (1/2)^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis

$$
\mbox{Evaluate}\quad
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}sx} \over
\left(\,{s - 7\mathrm{i}/2}\,\right)^{2} + \left(\,{1/2}\,\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}s
$$

Here I am having trouble as using simply the fourier inverse of $2\left\vert\,{a}\,\right\vert/\left(\,{s^{2} + a^{2}}\,\right)$ which is $\mathrm{e}^{-\left\vert\,{ax}\,\right\vert}$ gives wrong answer as denominator has
$s-7\mathrm{i}/2$.

I can do convolution theorem and then find inverse, but I want to directly evaluate from this expression.

Thank you !.

And if this requires residue theorem, where can I learn this ?.

Comment: Hint: use auxiliary variable $z=s-7i/2$. Then, using substitution, $dz=ds$ and $exp(isx)=exp(izx)\exp(-7/2x)$

Comment: @cjferes thanks but this gives $e^{-4x}$ but answer should be $e^{-3x} - e^{-4x}$ for positive $x$ (multiplied by some constant like $2\pi$)

Comment: @jeea: What is the convention that you use for the Fourier (and the inverse Fourier) transform? Also, are you familiar with distributions or with contour integration and residues of meromorphic functions?

Comment: @AlexM. Fourier transform => $F\{f(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-iwt} dt$ and inverse transform of $F(w)$ as $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(w) e^{iwx} dw$..... No I am not familiar with distribution or the contour integration, but can follow if I find introductory resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not familiar with complex analysis, we shall resort to using differential equations (these two are, in fact, the most used methods when dealing with integrals that depend on parameters).

Using [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), we have that

$$\int _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac {\mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {(s - \frac {7 \mathrm i} 2)^2 + (\frac 1 2)^2} \ \mathrm d s = \lim _{R \to \infty} \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {(s - \frac {7 \mathrm i} 2)^2 + (\frac 1 2)^2} \ \mathrm d s \ .$$

Next, notice that

$$\frac 1 {(s - \frac {7 \mathrm i} 2)^2 + (\frac 1 2)^2} = \frac 1 {(s - \frac {7 \mathrm i} 2)^2 - (\frac {\mathrm i} 2)^2} = \frac 1 {(s - 3 \mathrm i) (s - 4 \mathrm i)} = \frac 1 {\mathrm i} \left( \frac 1 {s - 4 \mathrm i} - \frac 1 {s - 3 \mathrm i} \right) ,$$

therefore your integral becomes

$$\frac 1 {\mathrm i} \lim _{R \to \infty} \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {s - 4 \mathrm i} \ \mathrm d s - \frac 1 {\mathrm i} \lim _{R \to \infty} \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {s - 3 \mathrm i} \ \mathrm d s \ .$$

For fixed $a > 0$ and $R>0$ let

$$I(x) = \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {s - a \mathrm i} \ \mathrm d s \ .$$

Using again Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, we may differentiate with respect to $x$ inside the integral, so

$$I'(x) = \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm i s \ \mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {s - a \mathrm i} \mathrm d s = \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm i (s - a \mathrm i + a \mathrm i) \ \mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {s - a \mathrm i} \mathrm d s = \mathrm i \int _{-R} ^R \mathrm e ^{\mathrm i s x} \mathrm d s - a \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {s - a \mathrm i} \mathrm d s = 2 \mathrm i \frac {\sin R x} x - a I(x) \ ,$$

which is a nonhomogeneous linear differential equation of order $1$ in $I$, which is easily solvable with the usual method and has for (unique) solution

$$I(x) = 2 \mathrm i \mathrm e ^{-ax} \int _{-\infty} ^x \mathrm e ^{a y} \frac {\sin R y} y \ \mathrm d y = 2 \mathrm i \mathrm e ^{-ax} \int _{-\infty} ^{Rx} \mathrm e ^{\frac {au} R} \frac {\sin u} u \ \mathrm d u \ .$$

For $x>0$ we deduce, using Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem for the third time (this should convince you about its importance), that

$$\lim _{R \to \infty} \int _{-R} ^R \frac {\mathrm e^{\mathrm i s x}} {s - a \mathrm i} \ \mathrm d s \ = \lim _{R \to \infty} I(x) = 2 \mathrm i \mathrm e ^{-ax} \lim _{R \to \infty} \int _{-\infty} ^{Rx} \mathrm e ^{\frac {au} R} \frac {\sin u} u \ \mathrm d u = 2 \mathrm i \mathrm e ^{-ax} \int _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac {\sin u} u \ \mathrm d u = 2 \pi \mathrm i \ \mathrm e ^{-ax}$$

whence, for $x>0$, the integral that you are looking for is found to be

$$2 \pi (\mathrm e^{-4x} - \mathrm e^{-3x}) \ .$$

(For various methods of computing $\int _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac {\sin u} u \mathrm d u$, you may look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192685/are-there-any-ways-to-evaluate-int-infty-0-frac-sin-xxdx-without-using-d) (and at the link therein) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175042/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xx-dx-with-fubini-theorem).)

If $x<0$ the, using the same approach as above, we get that $\lim _{R \to \infty} \int _{-\infty} ^{Rx} = \int _{-\infty} ^{-\infty} = 0$, therefore the desired integral is $0$.

Finally, for $x=0$, we could devise some complicated method to compute the corresponding integral, but it is easier to notice that the inverse Fourier transform will be continuous at $0$, and since the lateral limits are $0$ (using the result obtained so far), then the integral itself must be $0$ for $x=0$.

To conclude, the desired result is $\begin{cases} 2 \pi (\mathrm e^{-4x} - \mathrm e^{-3x}), & x>0 \\ 0, & x \le 0 \end{cases}$.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks a lot! but just one question, why using fourier inverse of $2\left\vert\,{a}\,\right\vert/\left(\,{s^{2} + a^{2}}\,\right)$ causes problem, if I directly apply it to be $e^{-|ax|}$. Actually this result was valid only for real $s$, but here $s-7i/2$ is imaginary, is that the problem with this one

Comment: Indeed, you have answered your own question very well. The formulae for the inverse Fourier transform that you know require functions of real arguments. As soon as some imaginary number shows up, the formulae are no longer valid and have to be corrected, and this is usually done with tools from complex analysis. Since you haven't studied this yet, I have provided you with a substitute, in the hope that you are familiar with the very basics of ordinary differential equations.